# Checking if a particular entry already present in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, search

I've a table `events` with the following fields:

```
`id`-->INT,PRIMARY AND AUTO_INCREMENT
`event_id`-->INT
`mem_1_id`-->INT
`mem_2_id`-->INT
`mem_3_id`-->INT
`mem_4_id`-->INT
`mem_5_id`-->INT
`mem_6_id`-->INT
```

All the `mem_x_id` `(0<x<7)` will be distinct for a particular `event_id` in `events` TABLE.
The `id` is the primary key that is normally used. A Possible example:

```
id  event_id    mem_1_id    mem_2_id    mem_3_id    mem_4_id    mem_5_id    mem_6_id
1   11          123         345         567         67          34          56
2   12          234         555         67          43          23          12
2   12          34          55          167         435         233         122
```

Now I want to check if the user's `id` (From  the `users` TABLE) who has logged in and is viewing the page of a particular event is present or not in `events` TABLE under that event's `id`. There may be multiple entries for a particular `event_id`
. I want to search in all those `event_id` that are of the event page.

My code is below: Please note, I'm new to PHP and hence still using the old version. I plan to get things working, and then modify my code to PDO. I'm learning PDO parallelly. But first I wish to make my code work.

```
$id=stores the event_id of the event page that the user is viewing.

$_SESSION['id']=`id` of the user that is logged in and viewing the page.

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    $result1=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM events WHERE event_id='".$id."')");
        if ($result1 == false) {
            echo mysql_error();
            die;
        }
        $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);

        if($row1['id']){
            if ($_SESSION['id']==$row1['mem_1_id'] || $_SESSION['id']==$row1['mem_2_id'] || $_SESSION['id']==$row1['mem_3_id'] || $_SESSION['id']==$row1['mem_4_id'] || $_SESSION['id']==$row1['mem_5_id'] || $_SESSION['id']==$row1['mem_6_id']){
                $is_already_regis=1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, you have to select all the fields you are going to use:

```
"SELECT id, mem_1_id, mem_2_id, [...], mem_6_id FROM events WHERE event_id='".$id."'"
```

Then, you have to use a loop to check each row:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    if ($_SESSION['id']==$row['mem_1_id'] || $_SESSION['id']==$row['mem_2_id'] || $_SESSION['id']==$row['mem_3_id'] || $_SESSION['id']==$row['mem_4_id'] || $_SESSION['id']==$row['mem_5_id'] || $_SESSION['id']==$row['mem_6_id']){
            $is_already_regis=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer with the loop to check all rows

Comment: This `while` loop will terminate when? I mean, are you sure it won't run indefinite times.

Comment: The `while` loop will end when there is no row left (`mysql_fetch_assoc` then returns `FALSE`)

Comment: My code was correct. There was this problem with the extra bracket at the end. `$result1=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM events WHERE event_id='".$id."')");`
Anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: Didn't spotted that parenthesis... Your code cannot be correct: your select query does not select columns `mem_X_id` (PHP should generate a notice for undefined index when using `$row['mem_X_id']`), and your code validates only the first row.

Comment: Ya sorry, I edited my comment, but guess there must have some problem with the edits. You were right. My method/code was incorrect. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just select and do an or to see if any of the mem_X_id fields matches the id for the current user. That saves you a lot of processing.